# How to loop local functions?

Tags: r, function, loops

I made a function in R that I would like to loop. I have gotten the function to work in a single case. I can't get the function to return the vector of number produced by the function.

```
vec_fun5 <- function(x,y){
  Vec <- c(round(mean(x[[y]],na.rm=T),2),nrow(na.omit(x[,y])),length(which(x[,y]==1)),length(which(x[,y]==2)),length(which(x[,y]==3)),length(which(x[,y]==4)),length(which(x[,y]==5)))
  return(Vec)
}

for(i in 20:24){
  vec_fun5(x,i)
}
```

I would like to produce a data frame with all of the vectors produced by the loop.

Comment: `sapply(20:24, function(i) vec_fun5(x, i))` will create a nice structure for you. Otherwise, you create an empty data frame of the right size and assign each ouput to the column or row you want it to go in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try putting the objects created by the function in a list:

```
vec_save <- list()

ii <- 1
for(i in 20:24){
 vec_save[[ii]] <- vec_fun5(x,i)
 ii <- ii+1
}
```

Following this, if you would like to `cbind` or `rbind` the vectors of interest to obtain a single dataframe, you can just run:

```
df <- do.call("cbind", vec_save) #assuming that you want to bind them by column
```